# Knockout Observable not updating when given a new value

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

This seems like the most basic part of using knockout, and I'm not sure why it isn't working, but for some reason , 2 of my 5 knockout observables are holding onto their new values.

In the setup of the model:

```
self.CProviderIdentifier = ko.observable();
self.ReferringProviderIdentifier = ko.observable();
self.BillableCareProviderIdentifier = ko.observable();
self.ServiceLocationIdentifier = ko.observable();
self.PracticeLocationIdentifier = ko.observable();
```

Inside of an AJAX call which returns a number of items inside of a JSON object, I extract the relevant pieces of information, and put them into the correct observable:

```
visitModel.CProviderIdentifier(data.CareProviderIdentifier);
visitModel.ReferringProviderIdentifier((data.ReferringProviderIdentifier == null ||
  data.ReferringProviderIdentifier == "undefined") ? 0 : data.ReferringProviderIdentifier);
visitModel.BillableCareProviderIdentifier(data.BillableCareProviderIdentifier);
visitModel.PracticeLocationIdentifier(data.PracticeLocationIdentifier);
visitModel.ServiceLocationIdentifier(data.ServiceLocationIdentifier);
```

Now, if none of them worked, it would make (some) sense, but only CProviderIdentifier and ReferringProviderIdentifier have no data. I've checked the data in a break point right before getting into setting the properties, and the values from data are 1003 and 0, but the two observables are undefined are the above block of code.

I'm working on getting a fiddle working for this: https://jsfiddle.net/bz3mq6z9/

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo in your `data` object? can you try: `var temp = data.CareProviderIdentifier; visitModel.CProviderIdentifier(temp);` and observe `temp` in the debugger?

Comment: That's how I figured out that the data was 1003 for CareProvider and 0 for ReferringProvider for my test item.

Comment: And what happens if you type a static value, say: `visitModel.CProviderIdentifier(12345);`?

Comment: Its still reading as undefined for some reason. I just tried both before setting the value like in the original question, or like you did in your comment. It was undefined afterwards both times.

Comment: How are you reading the value?

Comment: I have breakpoints in the javascript console in chrome and I'm calling visitModel.CProviderIdentifier() in the console at the breakpoint. I also tried alerting to the same effect.

Comment: Create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Maybe the error is in the view. How are you printing the value? Put an `alert(visitModel.CProviderIdentifier())` in the end of the code to see what happens

Comment: Second @Amit. We need a repro to be able to help you, otherwise we can only resort to guessing I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

The assignment is made in the loadData function. Inside it, Javascript does not know what is visitModel. That variable does not exist and does not have any purpose in the setter.

Use self instead of visitModel. That way knockout knows that he is assigning values to the view model

Greetings

Answer (score -1):

You have some bugs in your code:

1. should bind viewmode with DOM using:

   `ko.applyBindings(visitModel);`
2. ko.observable is a function, so you should use call it before combine string.

   `<span data-bind="text: CProviderIdentifier() + 'cp'"></span>`
3. it's not a good idea use `visitModel` in `LoadData` function, you can just use `self` to keep the reference.

see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bz3mq6z9/6/